# Sublime 3 PHP/HTML syntax highlighting

Tags: php, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

[image]

This image sums it up. Whenever I write a PHP tag "inside" a PHP tag that ends in open brackets [if, else, for, ...], the rest of the line becomes white.

**EDIT:** @MattDMo opened an issue in Sublime github repo and seems like they already commited a fix for it. Now we just have to wait for a deploy :)

Comment: ask on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @PedroLobito From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover "*[...] software tools commonly used by programmers*". Sublime Text, like vim, emacs, Notepad++, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext2+or+sublimetext3+or+sublimetext+or+vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+notepad%2b%2b) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with the PHP syntax highlighting definition. I'll open a new [issue](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues) momentarily. I can't think of a viable workaround at this point.

Comment: I've added a reference to [this existing issue](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/387) in the sublimehq/Packages repo. I know that the syntax definitions are under active development, so hopefully they can work something out. If anyone is good with `sublime-syntax` files and wants to submit a PR, please feel free.

Comment: @MattDMo seems like they took your issue seriously and already commited a fix for it! Thanks for everything!

Comment: @magroski no prob. Just so everyone knows what to do as a workaround until the next release, I'll write a quick answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is an [issue](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/387) with the `PHP.sublime-syntax` file in recent Sublime Text 3 builds. As explained in this [pull request](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/425), there are some things going on behind the scenes when PHP and HTML code mix, especially when HTML is inside of a curly brace block. The PR was accepted, and [the current version](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/tree/master/PHP) of the PHP package should now work as expected. To upgrade your installation of ST3, Build 3080 or later (and you **really** should be using the current [Build 3114](https://sublimetext.com/3) of the public beta, or [Build 3113](https://sublimetext.com/3dev) on the dev track), change to a temp directory or someplace and run

```
git clone https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages.git
```

or download the [zipfile](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/archive/master.zip) of the repo and expand it. Enter the created `Packages` directory, then copy the entire `PHP` folder to Sublime's `Packages` directory:

- OSX - `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Linux - `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- Windows - `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows portable install - `InstallationDirectory\Data\Packages`

***Please*** keep in mind that this will override (but not overwrite) Sublime's default PHP package, and *will not be upgraded* when you install a new build, with will almost certainly have additional changes as well. Simply remember to delete the new `Packages/PHP` directory upon upgrade, and you'll be all set.